# Android start activity when app started

Tags: android

This android project is about Webview. 
It start the activity when it click some button called goURL. 
but is it possible to start some activity when the app started?(not activity from the button). 
my guess is put something on onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}


public void goURL(View view){
    TextView tvURL = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtURL);
    String url = tvURL.getText().toString();
    Log.i("URL", "Opening URL with WebView :" + url);

    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

//webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


webView.loadUrl(url);
```

My guess is that to create intent about view.
but not sure how to do it

Comment: Yes, you can directly put your code in `onCreate()` method instead of `view` click method.

Answer (score 0):

You define in your Manifest.xml (or in Android Studio) which activity will be your MainActivity, which in turn is opened first, which then calls the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put the code in onCreate() function.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just load your webView reference and webView.loadUrl("http://..") in your onCreate section.

Make sure you've added the permission request in your manifest

A good tutorial - https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Answer (score 0):

to start activity call this in `onCreate`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and set activity in manifest `application`

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out the first activity which is displayed to the user when he starts the app from your Manifest.xml .
2. In this activity's onCreate() method add:

   ```
   TextView tvURL = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtURL);
   String url = tvURL.getText().toString();
   Log.i("URL", "Opening URL with WebView :" + url);
   final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
   //webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
   webView.loadUrl(url);
   ```
3. Use intent inside onCreate() , if you want to launch your activity
4. Otherwise you can make any activity as starting activity of your app by using intent-filter tag in Manifest.xml.